# Linq to Sql Add Child records

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two entities in Linq to Sql setup as a Parent/Child relationship (Parent can have many Children).  I have an existing parent record and trying to create new child records to be "added" to the parent.  Let's use the familiar Order and OrderDetails model for explanation.

I am trying a bunch of things to add my "child" to the parent record, but when I call SubmitChanges() on the data context, my newly created data is not "inserted" to the database.

For example, I have tried:

```
MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();
Order existingOrder = context.Orders.SingleOrDefault(o => p.OrderID == orderID);
OrderDetail newDetail = new OrderDetail();
//fill in order details here...

//ESTABLISH THE LINK SUCH THAT NEW RECORD IS CREATED
existingOrder.OrderDetails.Add(newDetail);

context.SubmitChanges();
```

I've also tried:

```
MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();
Order existingOrder = context.Orders.SingleOrDefault(o => p.OrderID == orderID);
OrderDetail newDetail = new OrderDetail();
//fill in order details here...

//ESTABLISH THE LINK SUCH THAT NEW RECORD IS CREATED
newDetail.OrderID = existingOrder.OrderID;
newDetail.Order = existingOrder;

context.SubmitChanges();
```

And a combination of the two:

```
MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();
Order existingOrder = context.Orders.SingleOrDefault(o => p.OrderID == orderID);
OrderDetail newDetail = new OrderDetail();
//fill in order details here...

//ESTABLISH THE LINK SUCH THAT NEW RECORD IS CREATED
newDetail.OrderID = existingOrder.OrderID;
newDetail.Order = existingOrder;
existingOrder.OrderDetails.Add(newDetail);

context.SubmitChanges();
```

The wierd thing is that both of these ways of handling things appear to be working on other places of the code base.  For example:

```
MyEntity myEntity = context.MyEntities.SingleOrDefault(e => e.MyEntityID = id);
myEntity.SelectedCategories.Add( 
    new SelectedCategory { MyEntityID = myEntity.MyEntityID , CategoryID = categoryId } 
);
context.SubmitChanges(); //correctly adds the new "many-to-many" record
```

What is the "Correct" way to do what I am attempting to do?  Do I need to explicitly call InsertOnSubmit() for each new item I am creating?  Is there now way to tell the model that anything added to the child collection should be added on submit?

Thanks!!

Comment: this is weird...are you sure the database relationships are setup right for the first 2 examples? I just tried doing something like this and it worked fine..

Comment: I reworked some code and now it is working.  I might have had a bug in there.  What is the appropriate, or "widely accepted" way for doing this?  The first or second approach?

Comment: I must have run into this inconsistency myself and assumed that `InsertOnSubmit` was the only way to go. Odd. I've removed my answer.

Comment: Can you update with your answer? This would be helpful for many people as updating child entities in linq-to-sql is a pain.